# Please suggest books (especially from Dover) that are good alternatives to Folland's and Royden's books for measure-theoretical real analysis.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, book-recommendation

Can you refer me to books that are at the same advanced level of real analysis via measure theory as Folland's and Royden's books? I want to have a solid foundation and I've been referred to books like Cohn's and Axler's, but I don't have deep knowledge of real analysis (I'm still going to start studying introduction to analysis) and I don't know if these books combine measure theory and real analysis like the ones I mentioned in the title or whether they are purely measure theory. If possible it was a Dover book because they have affordable prices here in Brazil.

Thanks to everyone who can help me.

Comment: Perhaps **Methods of Real Analysis** by Richard Robinson Goldberg ([1964 1st edition](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.134296) and [1976 2nd edition](https://alansinyal.files.wordpress.com/2012/08/method-of-real-analysis.pdf)), although this is a bit lower level than Royden and Folland. Slightly more advanced (and  much greater coverage of interesting lesser known results) than Goldberg is [**Basic Real and Abstract Analysis**](https://archive.org/details/basicrealabstrac00rand) by John Adams Fitz Randolph (1968).

Comment: I suggest *Introductory Real Analysis* by Kolmogorov and Fomin which is a Dover book. Measure theory begins in later chapters but probably it doesn't assume functional analysis parts of the book.